# AWK: shortened if-then-else with regex

Tags: regex, awk, syntactic-sugar

The following AWK format:

```
/REGEX/ {Action}
```

Will execute `Action` if the current line matches `REGEX`.

Is there a way to add an `else` clause, which will be executed if the current line does not matches the regex, without using if-then-else explicitly, something like:

```
/REGEX/ {Action-if-matches} {Action-if-does-not-match}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not so short:

```
/REGEX/ {Action-if-matches} 
! /REGEX/ {Action-if-does-not-match}
```

But (g)awk supports the ternary operator too:

```
{ /REGEX/  ? matching=1 : matching = 0 ; if ( matching ==1 ) { matching_action } else { notmatching_action } }
```

*UPDATE*:

According to the great Glenn Jackman you can assign variables on the match like:

```
m = /REGEX/ { matching-action } !m { NOT-matching-action }
```

Comment: Is that ternary supposed to be *inside* the braces? If so, does it actually do what OP asked for?

Comment: You were right, you cant perform "actions" other than assigning values with the ternary checking.

Comment: You could assign the boolean value of the match: `m = /regex/ {matching action} !m {non-matching action}`

Answer (score 16):

There's also `next`:

```
/REGEX/ {
    Action
    next # skip to the next line
}
{ will only get here if the current line does *not* match /REGEX/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "trick". As you know AWK tries to match the input to each regex in order, to execute its block.

This code executes the second block if $1 is "1", else it executes the third block:

```
awk '{used = 0} $1 == 1 {print $1" is 1 !!"; used = 1;} used == 0 {print $1" is not 1 !!";}'
```

If the input is:

```
1
2
```

It prints:

```
1 is 1 !!
2 is not 1 !!
```