# Conditional gsub action

Tags: if-statement, awk

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478722/awk-shortened-if-then-else-with-regex) answer, I am trying to reproduce a conditional statement where, in the event of a match, a substitusion occurs (it matches dates). If no match happens, the line is printed as it is.

```
#!/bin/bash

cleaner(){
        ./date_remove.awk $1 
}

cleaner $1 > "out"
```

where 'date_remove.awk' is

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

date = /(^|[^[:alpha:]])[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{3,8}[[:space:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{4}([^[:alpha:]]|$)/ {gsub(date, "")} !date {print}
```

At this point the substitution does not happens. 'gsub' should return only the matched phrases, but it does not return anything, actually. Just unmatched phrases are printed correctly. At this point, I am pretty sure is a problem of syntax, but I cannot figure out where.

Input:

```
ci sono 4444444444444Quattro mele
sentiamoci         il 16 Ottobre 2018
deciIIIIIIdiamo il 17 ottabre 2017
Manipolo di eroi 55555555555
17       mele
18 ott      2020 llllllLLLLLLLLLLLL
una mela e mezza
2 mAAAeleA
0000 asd a0        0 ad000
```

Actual output:

```
ci sono 4444444444444Quattro mele
Manipolo di eroi 55555555555
17       mele
una mela e mezza
2 mAAAeleA
0000 asd a0        0 ad000
```

Expected output:

```
ci sono 4444444444444Quattro mele
sentiamoci         il
deciIIIIIIdiamo il 
Manipolo di eroi 55555555555
17       mele
                  llllllLLLLLLLLLLLL
una mela e mezza
2 mAAAeleA
0000 asd a0        0 ad000
```

Comment: Could you please samples of input and output too so that question will be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite correct, `gsub()` does not return the matched phrases on its own. It just returns the count of substitutions made. Your problem is dealing with how to store the matching group for subsequent string replacement.

The problem with your attempt is the regexp matched within `/../` is not stored explicitly, you need to make it be stored by using `match()` or `index()` and use that in the replacement part,

```
awk '
    match($0, /(^|[^[:alpha:]])[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{3,8}[[:space:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{4}([^[:alpha:]]|$)/) {
        str=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); sub(str," ",$0 );
    }1' file
```

The example above would replace the captured group i.e. your date strings below and replace them with a single white space.

```
 16 Ottobre 2018
 17 ottabre 2017
18 ott      2020
```

One could use `sub()` or `gsub()` depending on the number of occurrences of the regex in the line. Applying the command above would remove the those date strings from the file and produce a result as below.

```
ci sono 4444444444444Quattro mele
sentiamoci         il 
deciIIIIIIdiamo il 
Manipolo di eroi 55555555555
17       mele
 llllllLLLLLLLLLLLL
una mela e mezza
2 mAAAeleA
0000 asd a0        0 ad000
```

Notice the `{..}1` after we do the string replace. It is needed to reconstruct the line after the appropriate replacements are done.

Putting it in `awk` script it would look like

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

match($0, /(^|[^[:alpha:]])[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{3,8}[[:space:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{4}([^[:alpha:]]|$)/) {
    str=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    sub(str," ",$0 )
}1
```

Comment: 'awk' appears to be far more deep and complex than expected. In any case, thank you for your answer. It is correct and sharp. More importantly, it made me realize the necessity to invest time in learning 'awk' and its background mechanics.

Comment: @Worice: It is a beautiful language, it is worth spending time for sure. The `/pattern/{action}` is one of the beautiful things available in Unix!